# c# local Service started and then stopped.. but works perfectly on my computer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-services

I’ve been developing this windows service to transfer some data from a local firebird database to an SQL one.

I don’t have an actual setup installer as I’m just getting to grips with services but I did include a Project Installer according to this tutorial
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx

**Here’s the beginning of it to get an idea:**

```
namespace MyNewService
{
    public partial class MyNewService : ServiceBase
    {
        public MyNewService()
        {InitializeComponent();}

        static Timer timer;

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
     this.AutoLog = false;
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "MySource", "MyLog");
            }
            eventLog1.Source = "MySource";

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 10000;//set interval
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            start_timer();
        }

        private void start_timer()
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart.");
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Starting Work. Time elapsed" + timer.Interval);

            string connFb = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FbConString"].ConnectionString;
            FbConnection FbCon = new FbConnection(connFb);

            string connSql = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(connSql);

            try
            {
  FbCon.Open();
                SqlCon.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e0)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("----------Exception Message: {0}" + e0.Message);
            }
            string FB1 = "SELECT FIRST 500 * FROM SC_JOBS ……";
            string sql1 = ("UPDATE Jobs SET JobID = @JId, …..)");
            using (FbCommand Command = new FbCommand(FB1, FbCon))
            {
                //Console.Write(line);
                DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
                try{
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT", date);
                    using (FbDataReader DbReader = Command.ExecuteReader())

                        while (DbReader.Read())
                        {
                            var Job = new Job();
                Job.JobID = Convert.ToInt32(DbReader["JOBSID"]);
// Some more processing going on...//
```

**And here is my Appconfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <switches></switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlConString" connectionString="user id=...; password=...;server=213.171....; database=...;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
    <add name="FbConString" connectionString="User=…;Password=….;Database=192.168…:C:\\Window Designer 7\\Database\\fdsdatabase.fds;DataSource=192.168….;Port=3050;Dialect=3;" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I install the service with **installutil** and, on my system at least, the service run perfectly fine. It also has no dependencies (just a firebird dll which is packed in the bin/debug folder with the service exe)
When I tried it on another pc (windows 8/.NET framework 4.5/ Visual studio express) it starts and stops for reasons I struggle to comprehend.

I don’t get any log messages though
I did come across this error in Event viewer (Windows Logs/Applications) but only once:

*“service is marked as an interactive service. However, the system is configured to not allow interactive services”*

**So here is what I’ve tried so far:**

- Clear Application logs- no change
- Enabling Interactive Service Detection – It doesn’t, I get
  Error1:Incorrect function
- Adding “System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();” into Main() to capture
  potential start-up errors I don’t get any debug options and I don’t
  know where to look for possible log entries

I know this question has been asked a lot before but what solutions I've gone through have not panned out for me. I’m on a deadline for this project so any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: could you please specify which operating system you are using

Comment: Window 8 on both machines/ I'm coding with VS 2012 but the 2nd pc has only the express version

Comment: As long as you are not trying to compile it on the vs2012 express machine, you should be able to install it with the installutil and to run it. When you install it regularly, could you try to let it run under different user credentials ? If this turns out to be working then i would suggest some userright issues

Comment: I've tried setting it "run local" in the service setting from VS (tools/options i think) and also on the other pc changed "Log on as Local system account" from Administrative/Services but to no avail. 
Is that what you meant?

Comment: P.S. I am able to install it with instalutil on the 2nd pc- it just does'nt run

Comment: Yes that was what i meant. Okay lets get a little bit dirty now :D. Could you try to make a console application which does call the onStart method ? when there is no userright reason why it fails to execute than i would guess that there is a problem with the settings

Comment: Hmm going a bit deep for me but I m liking the way you think. I ve done some cmd apps but I ve not done that before. Can you give me some pointers?
Like would it be an app in the same project calling it or a completely separate entity

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the condition where a service starts and immediately stops occurs for one of two reasons.

The first reason is that the programmer did not have the service doing anything, i.e., it did not run a thread to keep the service going.  Given that your service works on your machine, this is not the issue.

The second reason is that an exception occurs in the service constructor or in the `OnStart` callback.  Looking at your code, your service constructor is minimal, so I doubt that's where the problem occurs.  However, your `OnStart` callback attempts to interact with the event log, which requires a certain amount of elevated user permissions.  If I had to guess, I would say that attempting to check whether "My Source" exists or (more likely) creating the "My Source" event source is throwing an exception that is not being caught nor being logged somehow.  To verify this, it'd be preferable to debug the service on the problem machine.  Of course, if you have sufficient user permissions, this might not be possible.  Thus, you could put a try-catch block around your the contents of `OnStart` and if an exception is occurring, create a text file in a folder you have permission to access (your Users folder, for example) and write the contents of the exception to that file, including the stack trace so you can get a clearer picture of what is going on.

If the problem is not in the `OnStart` callback, the next place to check would be your timer callback function.

HTH

Comment: Well, in the end I delegated a part of the service tasks (and timers) to a command-line application and got it to work.
I still cant figure out the reason behind it. 
Though I could always see "My Log" in the Event Log after install -just had no entries-
I am inclined to agree its likely about some kind of permissions.